# counting different types of transactions in different locations. python

Tags: python, counting

I have a class called transactions with the following attributes.

```
transactions = ([time_of_day, day_of_month ,week_day, duration, amount, trans_type, location])
```

this is the sample data types

```
time    date    weekday duration    amount  type       location
0:07    3       thu      2                  balance    driveup
0:07    3       thu      6          20      withdrawal campusA
0:20    1       tue      2          357     deposit    campusB
```

the type of transactions are

```
balance, withdrawal, deposit, advance, transfer
```

i have to count the number of different types of transaction in different location
which will result in something like this

```
Location | Advance | Balance | Deposit | Transfer | Withdrawal | Total
'driveup'|     4   |     191 |    247  |       28 |        530  |  1000 
'campus' |     1   |      2  |    3    |     4    |      5      |  15
```

the result should emit a list, something like this:

```
 [['Location', 'Advance', 'Balance', 'Deposit', 'Transfer', 'Withdrawal', 'Total'],  
['driveup', 4, 191, 247, 28, 530, 1000],['campus', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15]]
```

note: the example data set and the resulting list only shows 1 location. there are 3 different locations. 'driveup', 'campusa', 'campusb'

how do i make the list?

i tried something like this

```
atm_location = list(zip(amounts, transactions, locations))

for element in atm_location
    a = element[1] #transactions
    b = element[2] #locations
    c = element[0] #amounts
    if a == 'advance' and b == 'driveup':
        drive_advance.append((a,b,c))
```

and etcetra, so i basically just do if and elifs condition, the code is very long so i wouldnt put it here.

Comment: homework?   what did you try to do?

Comment: You could read the [docs on DataFrame.stack()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and give it shot yourself.

Comment: @joop yes correct. i tried to count the each transactions types in each location, then total all of them. i can count each transaction type one by one in just one location. but im not sure how to start to count the different location all together.

Comment: you can show us what you have so far.

Comment: @taesu ive put the code up

Comment: for loop seems broken

Comment: sorry sintax error @taesu

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 can you answer this?? :)